# Application Displays Unstyled Html Before It Renders Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am dynamically adding markup to my application an example code below..

```
$(document).bind("pagechange", function (event, ui) {
  var header = '<h3>' + appNames[i] + '</h3>';

        var ulHeader = '<ul data-role="listview" id="myAppsGridTable" data-inset="true">';

..
   $('.myBodyContent', ui.toPage).append(collapse + header + ulHeader + entire_list + '</ul>' + '</div>');
    $('#NicksPage').trigger('create');

});
```

I have a reference to this page in my Default.aspx page and a reference to jquery mobile in the master page. When you navigate to Default the user sees raw unstlyed html added to the page then a flicker and the jquery mobile styles come in. Is there anyway I can get rid of displaying the unstlyed html to the user sees before the jquery mobile styles are added?

Here is a copy of my master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserMobile.master.cs" Inherits="User.Mobile.UserMobile" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="Css/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Css/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="NicksPage">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">

         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TopHeaderContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" class="myBodyContent"> 

 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FooterContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    <input type="hidden" id="collapse_value" value="false" />
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

   //Combined jquery 1.8 and jquery mobile files in one
   <script src="Js/JQ_JQM_combined.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    //Makes ajax calls to get data
    <script src="Js/UserMobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // disable page transitions
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
        });

    </script>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</body>

</html>
```

Even the Home page has the flicker problem, where it renders unstyled and then after a period of time properly styled to jquery mobile..

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Mobile/UserMobile.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="User.Mobile.Home" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="TopHeaderContent" runat="server">
    <h1>
        Applications</h1>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div data-role="controlgroup">
<a href="MyStuff.aspx?name=nick&id=1234" data-role="button">My Stuff</a>
<a href="Employees.aspx?name=nick&id=1234" data-role="button">Employees</a>
<a href="list.aspx?name=nick&id=1234" data-role="button">List</a>

</div>


</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="FooterContent" runat="server">
    <div class="lines">
        <div class="footerCopyrightContainer">
            <div class="footerCopyright">
                &copy;2012 NICK ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I changed my code to reflect your fiddle example but am still getting the flicker. But the "period of time where the flicker the unstyled to styled is shorter the user still sees the unstyled page in the mobile browser. Can you take a look fo how I got it setup am I missing something?

```
$(document).bind("pagecreate", function (event, ui) {

    //gets params needed from querystring
    arrQrStr = getQueryStringParams();
    name = arrQrStr["name"];
    id = arrQrStr["id"];

});


$(document).delegate('div[data-role=page]', 'pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {

    var employees = null;

    //returns string of html needed
    employees = getData(name, id);

    $('.myBodyContent', this).html(employees);

    $(this).trigger('create');

});
```

getData ajax call..

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MobileService.svc/REST/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: id}),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
```

The problem has comes from this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {


          // disable page transitions
          $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';



      });


    </script>
```

If I take this out of the master page the flicker goes away, it navigates a page fine but the data will not show. Taking this script out breaks the ajax calls and jquery mobile events dont engage (I am not sure why)

Comment: Does the `getData` function use an asynchronous process like AJAX?

Comment: it uses ajax but async is set to false

Comment: There's a chance that using a synchronous request is creating your flicker. Rather than using an AJAX request to get the data, why not link to an external document that uses a Server Side Language to get the data and create the necessary page? It feels like you're over complicating the issue...

Comment: I am even getting the flicker on the home page that is getting no data back.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how WCF services work, but if you can get the data via JS then you can get it via whatever Server Side Language you want. Then use that Server Side Language to create the actual HTML document, jQuery Mobile will do the rest. If you're creating a synchronous AJAX request but not getting data, you're still going to "freeze-up" the client's browser. That's the problem with synchronous requests, nothing else is aloud to happen while it's running, so it appears to the user that the page has frozen until it completes.

Comment: Are you only experiencing this flicker when you get the data via `ajax`? What about if you add it manually? I tried reproducing your issue using a master page and two content pages with a link from one to the other manually building up a list of about 25 items and I didn't experience any flicker, but I might be missing something from your setup.

Comment: I see I missed your comment that your home page doesn't get any data back and also experiences this flicker. Is it only on a mobile device? Because I don't see any flicker on my desktop.

Comment: I comes from the the document.ready script in the master page (shown above) if I take that scrpt out the flicker goes away, but then the jquery mobile pagenotbefore event wont fire if that is taken out

Comment: Jquery mobile seems to nee ajax enabled to false AND pagetransition to none in order for any jquery mobile events to fire, but with this comes the flicker. How can I get the events to fire without setting these things in document ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you misunderstood how the [ajax enabled](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html) settings works.

By default this setting is enabled and when you link to another page JQM pulls in the the first JQM page that it finds (`data-role="page"`) on the linked page (so you can't link to a `multipage` document) and *enhances* it (initializing all the JQM widgets) and then attaches it to the DOM of the current page. When JQM does this it **only** pulls in the JQM page and *nothing else* on that page (so any scripts and styling on the second page [won't](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) have any effect). The way to deal with this is to have all your scripts in the current *main* page. One thing you will need to look out for if you do this is that you might end up with multiple pages with the same `id` (actually with your current setup you definitely will have duplicate `ids`) so you might want to select them by `class` instead.

With `ajax enabled` set to `false` on the other hand it behaves like a regular link in which case the full page is loaded and if your JQM scripts are on the bottom then then until it's loaded it won't be able to enhance the DOM which is why you are seeing that flicker.

As a side point `page transistions are only available if`ajax enabled`is set to`true`.

To sum up, unless you have a reason not to you probablly should go with `ajax enabled` set to true, and inlcude the relevant scripts on your main page. If you need to go with `ajax enabled` set to `false` then try placing your jQuery scripts in the header so that they load before the rest of the DOM.

Alternaticely what you can do is hide the container element where you will be appending you html and then once your done display it, for example

CSS

```
.displayNone { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
 <div data-role="content" class="myBodyContent displayNone"> 
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

JS

```
 $('.myBodyContent', this).html(employees);
    $(this).trigger('create');
    $('.myBodyContent', this).reomveClass('displayNone');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your jquery mobile source scripts in the head, instead of at the end of the body.

This is the only way I could guarantee that the user never sees unstyled html.

Comment: I tried the flicker is still there it has to somehow be connected to turning on and off the doc ready script which in turns breaks the jquery mobile events

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `pagebeforeshow` instead of `pagechange`. Like so:

```
$(document).delegate('div[data-role=page]', 'pagebeforeshow', function(e, data){
    var toPage = this; // this references the page that is about to be shown
    // Add items to the page
});
```

The `pagebeforeshow` event is triggered on the "toPage" being transisioned to, before the actual transition animation starts. This allows you to add in elements and styles before it is displayed to the user.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rthpv/5/) with the suggested fix implemented.

Comment: So in my code I change ui.toPage to toPage here  $('.myBodyContent', ui.toPage) and subscribe to your event like shown?

Comment: @NickLaMarca Can you plz take a look at this JSFiddle with the implemented fix as above: http://jsfiddle.net/Rthpv/5/. Can you see if this works, and if not modify the fiddle to reproduce your error so that I can provide an answer.Thank you.

Comment: I added a page/masterpage with the issue to the question